# Importing vCard in Android via code

Tags: java, android, import, vcf-vcard

I exported my contacts as vCard using the API at ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI.
It runs without any problem and I have a vcf-file with all my contacts.

Now I'm trying to **import** these contacts. I searched the web, and I see, that many other people asked how to do that, but I didn't found any code example...

Someone say, I have to use external libraries, but Android **must** have a code to import the vCard, otherwise it can't do that (in the contact manager, I can just select a vcf-file and import it. It does have an API to import vCard).
Someone other say, that I can use internal API, but I can't find any API to import vCard.

Can someone say me, how can I import these vCards? I have a String with just **one** vCard, and I need to import it, just using Java...

Thanks a lot for you help!
Luca Bertoncello

Answer (score 0):

try using the code bellow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file-path.vcf,"text/vcard");  
startActivity(intent);
```